# GIT release new version of repository

Tags: git, release

I'm trying to release my stable private library by doing the next:

Edited composer.json

```
"version": "1.0.0" => "version": "2.0.0"
```

Commit with message "Release 2.0.0" and `git tag 1.0.0 -m "Release 1.0.0"`

But now I'm looking to my repo and see none tags. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
git tag -l
```

To list the tags in your local repository.

Use

```
git ls-remote --tags [remote]
```

To list the remote --tags (ignore the leading refs/)

If you see the tag local but not remote you need to push it explicit by

```
git push [remote] [tag]
```

or all tags by

```
git push --tags [remote]
```

Use

```
git show [tag]
```

To show details of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use `--tags` key of `git push` when pushing to public repo.